# to distribute iPhone App for an commercial software-product

Tags: iphone, distribution

if you have a product and would like to have an iPhone Application for this commercial product (this application just communicates with web service and presents some data)

how can you distribute this iPhone-App by customers of this product?
only about Apple-Store?
Would Apple allow to store there an application for the commercial product?
Can be this application free?

Thank you so much!
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. There are many products like this in the App Store already. You will just have to provide Apple with demo accounts they can use during the approval process to test your application. Neither of the other distribution models (Ad Hoc, Enterprise) will work for what you want because you need the device id or physical access to the device.

Comment: but if you store the free-applicationfor (because you supply this with your commercial product ) - apple doesn't earn money with it.

of course, the win, because your client will buy iphones:)

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to distribute your app for free (because it is bundled to a commercial product anyway) you could circumvent the App Store by creating a web based application.

[Nextstop](http://scobleizer.com/2009/12/16/iphone-developers-abandoning-app-model-for-html5/) is a good example that it is possible to create web apps which feel native.

Comment: I'd like to build a native App, do you think it will be a problem with the AppStore?

Comment: not necessarily, but compared to deploying a web app it is certainly more hassle because of bureaucratic waiting times. so I would recommend to build a web based app if you don't intend to charge for it and if you don't need access to features which are only available via the native api.